# Django - The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

My website, which was working before, suddenly started breaking with the error

> ImproperlyConfigured at / The included urlconf resume.urls doesn't
>   have any patterns in it

The project base is called resume.  In settings.py I have set

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'resume.urls'
```

Here's my resume.urls, which sits in the project root directory.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^resume/', include('resume.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),


    #(r'^employer/', include(students.urls)),

    (r'^ajax/', include('urls.ajax')),
    (r'^student/', include('students.urls')),
    (r'^club/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'resume.students.views.club_detail'),
    (r'^company/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'resume.students.views.company_detail'),
    (r'^program/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'resume.students.views.program_detail'),
    (r'^course/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'resume.students.views.course_detail'),
    (r'^career/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'resume.students.views.career_detail'),

    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'C:/code/django/resume/media'}),

)
```

I have a folder called urls and a file ajax.py inside.  (I also created a blank **init**.py in the same folder so that urls would be recognized.)  This is ajax.py.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^star/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', 'resume.students.ajax-calls.star'),
)
```

Anyone know what's wrong?  This is driving me crazy.

Thanks,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check your patterns for include statements that point to non-existent modules or modules that do not have a `urlpatterns` member. I see that you have an `include('urls.ajax')` which may not be correct. Should it be `ajax.urls`?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the code from ajax.py.  I also tried commenting the includes out--still no dice.

Comment: You can't have a `urls.py` and a directory named `urls` in the same package. If you want to have `resume.urls` and `resume.urls.ajax`, then you will need to move all of the contents of `urls.py` into `urls/__init__.py` and delete the `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 101):

TL;DR: You probably need to use `reverse_lazy()` instead of `reverse()`

If your `urls.py` imports a class-based view that uses `reverse()`, you will get this error; using `reverse_lazy()` will fix it.

For me, the error

> The included urlconf project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

got thrown because:

- `project.urls` imported `app.urls`
- `app.urls` imported `app.views`
- `app.views` had a class-based view that used `reverse`
- `reverse` imports `project.urls`, resulting in a circular dependency.

Using [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead of [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) solved the problem: this postponed the reversing of the url until it was first needed at runtime.

Moral: Always use `reverse_lazy` if you need to reverse before the app starts.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem in Django 1.6.5. I happens when i add this line to a DeleteView: `success_url = reverse_lazy('client_list')` and stops when i hard code the URL :(

Comment: This was it for me! Reverse should not be used if the app is trying to load the URLConf, since reverse requires looking at the URLConf.

Comment: Worth pointing out that reverse_lazy is necessary if you're passing the output into `@login_required(login_url=)`. I think this is because you're reversing before the app starts.

Answer (score 12):

check for correct variable name in your app, if it is "

> urlpatterns

" or any thing else.
Correcting name helped me

Comment: Nice, I had url_patterns

Comment: This one needs more up votes, nice observation!

Comment: changing name from url_patterns to urlpatterns works for me .
cool

Answer (score 4):

Check the name of the variable.

The cause of my error was using `"urlspatterns"` in lieu of `"urlpatterns"`.

Correcting the name of the variable solved the issue for me.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479441/3216427

Comment: same as however I used "urlpattterns"

Answer (score 2):

IN my case I got this error during deployment. 
Apache kept giving me the "AH01630: client denied by server configuration" error.
This indicated that was wrong with apache configuration. To help troubleshoot I had turned on Debug=True in settings.py when I saw this error.

In the end I had to add a new directive to the static files configuration inside apache config. When the static files were not accessible and Debug in django settings was set to true this error was getting triggered somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to reverse (and reverse_lazy) using RedirectView and parameters from the url. The offending code looked like this:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url(r'^(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse('dailyreport_location', args=['%(location_id)s', ]))),
```

The fix is to use this url in urlpatterns:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
url(r'^(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/statistics/dailyreport/%(location_id)s/')),
```

**ANSWER**: The fix so you can still use the name of the url pattern:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', lambda x, location_id: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dailyreport_location', args=[location_id])), name='location_stats_redirect'),
    ....
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of tuple unpacking. I only had one url and the root cause for this `ImproperlyConfigured` error was

```
TypeError: 'URLPattern' object is not iterable
```

I used a trailing comma at the end and it resolved the issue.

```
urlpatterns = (url(...) , )
```

Answer (score 1):

`django.urls.reverse()`-->`django.urls.reverse_lazy()`
This will instantly solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

The url patterns were valid, but the problem was an Import error caused by a typo. I typed `restframework` instead of `rest_framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For some reason, for me this error also went away after I saved another file. So the first time the error appeared, I had saved a file in which I specified the wrong widget in the `forms.py` file:

```
extra_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextField())
```

instead of

```
extra_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

After changing it to the correct version (TextInput) and saving the forms.py file, the error was still showing in my console. After saving another file (e.g. models.py) the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check the imported modules in views.py if there is any uninstalled modules you found remove the module from your views.py file.
It's Fix for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case **using comma** at the end of path in App's **urls.py** solved the issue.

example:-

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.index, name='app')**,**
]
```

stars in the code are for highlighting the comma only.

Answer (score 0):

django.urls.reverse() to django.urls.reverse_lazy() This will instantly solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yet *another* possible cause for this type of error is the improper use of `reverse()` or `reverse_lazy()`.

For example, if you inadvertently confuse the signature of [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) with that of the [`url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url), and do something like this

```py
reverse('my_view_name', 123)
```

then you'll see

```
The included URLconf '123' does not appear to have any patterns in it.
```

That should be something like

```py
reverse('my_view_name', args=[123])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using a class based view `UpdateView` and in `sucess_url` attribute i was passing

```
sucess_url = redirect(reverse('my url name'))
```

But it break the code, because for some reason behind the scenes Django already make a redirect giving a error of "urlpatterns failed or circular import".

For solve this just remove redirect function and your code will work normally

```
sucess_url = reverse('your url name')
```