# url redirect is not working in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', redirect('home')),
    url(r"^home/$", 'my_project.views.user_login', name="home"),
    #url(r'^/$', redirect('home')),
)
```

I want to direct `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` to same view for processing.
I have other urlpatterns which I have not included above for simplicity.
Currently, it throws the following error when I access this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/`:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /home/
The included urlconf cmv_project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
The included urlconf cmv_project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

when I comment-out the second urlpattern (`url(r'^$', redirect('home')),`), it works.
I tried to switch the this urlpattern to the last. but it still did not help. Having this pattern, breaks other Urlpatterns, in the urls.py. I dont't know why?
how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to attach the second url to the same view as the third url use something like this.

```
url(r"^$",my_project.views.user_login, name="home")
```

Another approach would be.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('home'))),
```

Does this work??

Comment: but that is not redirecting and is not DRY?

Comment: It is a very crude way of directing but it would work

Answer (score 0):

I think it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011179/django-the-included-urlconf-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it). Basically, when you use `redirect` with a name, it's going to use `reverse` to find it. See [example 2 here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples). You'll need to use `reverse_lazy` instead.

To fix this, you could either do:

```
redirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
```

or:

```
redirect('home/')
```

Note that if you do the first option, you'll need to import `reverse_lazy`. If you do the second option, you're hard-coded which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the name mentioned in the urls.py within the redirect method, we must use within quote as like:

```
redirect(articles, year = "2045", month = "02") is wrong 

redirect('articles', year = "2045", month = "02") is right
```