# Circular import in Django 2 python "urls" file

Tags: python, django

I have request login API using Django framework but error through in "**circular import**" error of URL patterns. please, anyone, give us a solution regarding point.

Error log write in log file:

```
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407794 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] Internal Server Error: /ai_chat_bot/users/login
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407814 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407816 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 542, in url_patterns
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407818 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     iter(patterns)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407821 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] 
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407822 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407823 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] 
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407825 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407826 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407828 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     response = get_response(request)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407829 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407831 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     response = self.process_request(request)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407832 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 60, in process_request
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407834 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     if self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407835 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 78, in should_redirect_with_slash
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407837 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     not is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407838 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 157, in is_valid_path
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407840 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407841 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407843 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407844 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 498, in resolve
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407845 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407856 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407858 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407859 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]   File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 549, in url_patterns
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407861 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440]     raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
[Sun Mar 10 20:30:47.407863 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21457:tid 139659590813440] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'AI_Chatbot_Server.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Source code of '**AI_Chatbot_Server.urls**' file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # chatbot app url list
    path('ai_chat_bot/', include("apps.chatbot.urls")),
    path('ai_chat_bot/users/', include("apps.users.urls")),
    path('ai_chat_bot/weather/', include("apps.weather.urls")),
]
```

**Update-1:**

User module urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .controller import login_controller

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', login_controller.LoginController.login, name='login'),
]
```

Chatbot module urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .controller import chatbot_main_controller

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_question/', chatbot_main_controller.ChatBotMainController.get_question, name="get_question"),
]
```

Weather module usrls:

```
from django.urls import path

from ..weather.controller import weather_info_controller

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_weather_info/', weather_info_controller.WeatherInfoController.get_weather_info, name="get_weather_info"),
]
```

**Update-2:**

I have shared folder structure of users, chatbot & weather module:

```
    .
├─.idea
├─AI_Chatbot_Server
│  └─settings
├─apps
│  ├─chatbot
│  │  ├─ai_models
│  │  │  ├─cnn
│  │  │  │  └─temp
│  │  │  ├─estimator
│  │  │  ├─multiclass_cnn
│  │  │  │  └─temp
│  │  │  ├─multiclass_dnn
│  │  │  │  └─temp
│  │  │  └─tensorflow
│  │  ├─ai_model_handler
│  │  ├─common
│  │  ├─config
│  │  ├─controller
│  │  ├─data_processor
│  │  ├─emoji
│  │  │  ├─common
│  │  │  ├─controller
│  │  │  ├─model
│  │  │  ├─repository
│  │  │  ├─serializer
│  │  │  └─service
│  │  ├─evaluation
│  │  │  ├─controller
│  │  │  ├─model
│  │  │  ├─repository
│  │  │  ├─serializer
│  │  │  └─service
│  │  ├─keyword
│  │  │  ├─common
│  │  │  ├─controller
│  │  │  ├─helper
│  │  │  ├─logic
│  │  │  ├─models
│  │  │  ├─repository
│  │  │  ├─serializer
│  │  │  └─service
│  │  ├─models
│  │  ├─repository
│  │  ├─serializer
│  │  ├─service
│  │  ├─utils
│  │  └─validation
│  ├─common
│  ├─users
│  │  ├─common
│  │  ├─controller
│  │  ├─json
│  │  ├─model
│  │  ├─repository
│  │  ├─serializer
│  │  └─service
│  └─weather
│      ├─common
│      ├─controller
│      └─service
├─common
└─static
    ├─data
    └─resources
        └─images
            └─emoji
```

**Update-3:**
I have added login controller, please check it.

```
import logging
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from ..common.http_code import HttpCode
from ..common.http_message import HttpMessage
from ..common.user_constant import UserConstant
from ..common.utility import Utility
from ..json.response import Response
from ..service.login_service import LoginService
from ..service.login_service import LoginService as loginService


class LoginController:
    logger = logging.getLogger('LoginController')

    @api_view(['POST'])
    def login(request):
        LoginController.logger.info("LoginController.login : START")
        http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_ZERO
        post_data = None
        responseData = None
        # check valid json format & added json format exception
        try:
            post_data = Utility.convertRequestBodyToJson(request)
        except JSONDecodeError as ex:
            responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.ERROR, str(ex.args), None)
            LoginController.logger.error(UserConstant.JSON_PARSE_ERROR + str(ex))
            http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST

        # check request param
        if post_data != None:
            username = post_data['username']
            password = post_data['password']

            # check valid user & password
            try:
                try:
                    valid_user = loginService.check_username(username)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    valid_user = None

                if valid_user != None:
                    decoded_password = loginService.decoded_password(valid_user)
                    if decoded_password == password:
                        # save user access with token
                        user_access = loginService.set_user_access(valid_user)
                        if user_access != None:
                            loginService.save_user_access(user_access)
                            user_role = loginService.get_user_role(valid_user)
                            login_service = LoginService()
                            # process user_access_history data
                            # login_service.process_user_access_history(valid_user.username, user_access.token)
                            if user_role != None:
                                # prepare the user response object
                                users = {'id': valid_user.id, 'username': valid_user.username,
                                         'token': user_access.token, 'role': user_role.name,
                                         'user_image_url': valid_user.user_image_url}
                                # added common method for prepare response object
                                responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.SUCCESS,
                                                                         UserConstant.USER_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESSFUL,
                                                                         users)
                                http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_OK
                    else:
                        responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.ERROR,
                                                                 UserConstant.INCORRECT_USER_PASSWORD, None)
                        http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
                else:
                    responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.ERROR, UserConstant.USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAIL,
                                                             None)
                    http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED

            except IntegrityError as ex:
                responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.ERROR, str(ex.args), None)
                LoginController.logger.error(UserConstant.DATABASE_ERROR + str(ex))
                http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            except Exception as ex:
                LoginController.logger.error(UserConstant.ERROR + str(ex))
                responseData = Response.preparedResponse(UserConstant.ERROR, HttpMessage.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, None)
                http_status_code = HttpCode.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        LoginController.logger.info("LoginController.login : END")
        return JsonResponse(status=http_status_code, data=responseData, safe=False)
```

Comment: does the `/admin/` url work on the browser?

Comment: Could you add some more files?

Comment: Please add all the `urls.py` files

Comment: Why you have `apps.chatbot.urls` not simply `chatbot.urls`?

Comment: @SammyJ admin panel its working.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi I have added another module "chatbot" in this project, that way I have to add url "apps.chatbot.urls"

Comment: does chatbot, users and weather comes under **apps**

Comment: @c.grey yes, i have created apps under 3 module chatbot, users and weather

Comment: hmm. I also doubt what @c.grey doubted. Could you share your folder structure? urls seems legit to me.

Comment: @Md.Nazmul check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011179/django-the-included-urlconf-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it this may solve the issue you are having. Also keep in mind checking replacing reverse with reverse_lazy in views

Comment: What does login_controller look like?

Comment: @Abbas I have updated my question, please check it.

Comment: @WaketZheng I have updated question, Please check it.

Comment: I can only see `users` under the app. `chatbot` and `weather` are not there. Try commenting out all the url imports other that admin and check. If it runs, then uncomment one by one to pin-point which one is causing the issue. Also, check if the `chatbot` and `weather` are your installed apps.

Comment: Totally unrelated but you're not using the `logging` correctly - your library code should NEVER call `logging.config()`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have updated question, Please check it

Comment: @Abbas I have updated project structure, please check it.

Comment: @Mayur I have added some code in question section, please check it.

Answer (score -1):

Let me search for you the `circular import` related issue from the documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/search/?q=circular+import

Below I have list down and try to give the responsible things of circular import.
As you have not share the full code so went through the documentation and re-factor your code
as document suggested. Hope this will help.

**1. Settings**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#message-level

> If you override MESSAGE_LEVEL in your settings file and rely on any of the built-in constants, you must import the constants module directly to avoid the potential for circular imports, e.g.:

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants
MESSAGE_LEVEL = message_constants.DEBUG
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#message-tags

> If you override MESSAGE_TAGS in your settings file and rely on any of the built-in constants, you must import the constants module directly to avoid the potential for circular imports, e.g.:

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants
MESSAGE_TAGS = {message_constants.INFO: ''}
```

**2 Coding style**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#imports

You may run "isort -rc" command for organized the imports.

**3 Translation**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

> If you define a custom LANGUAGES setting, as explained in the previous bullet, you can mark the language names as translation strings – but use gettext_lazy() instead of gettext() to avoid a circular import.
>
> Here’s a sample settings file:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

**4 Django 1.7 release notes**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.7/#django-utils-module-loading-import-by-path

**5 Model field reference**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'production.Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

> This sort of reference, called a lazy relationship, can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies between two application.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

**6. Model signals**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/

**7. Customizing authentication in Django**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

**8. Advanced testing topics**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#controlling-creation-order-for-test-databases

**9. Migrations**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

There may have other issues but it may help you a little bit.