# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'basic_app.urls' from 'C:\Users\shree\learning_users\basic_app\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

code in basic_app.url

```
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

url_patterns = [

     path('register', views.register, name='register'),

]
```

code in learning_users.url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from basic_app import views
# from django.conf.urls import url,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls')),
]
```

Comment: It should be **`urlpatterns`**, not `url_patterns`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011179/django-the-included-urlconf-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it)

Answer (score 2):

it should be `urlpatterns` not `url_patterns`.