# does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import .Django 3.0.2

Tags: django, django-urls

**Project name : CRMPROJECT**

**App name: leads**

I'm working on a CRM project With Django and I keep getting this error while trying to map my urls to views

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it**

Below is the project/urls.py file

```
'''


from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include

from leads import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('leads/',include('leads.urls',namespace='leads')),
     ]

'''
```

**Below is leads/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'leads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
]
```

And lastly my leads/views.py

```
'''
 
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'leads/base.html')

'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011179/django-the-included-urlconf-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it)

Comment: It doesn't help sadly